# Can I use the Request Header somewhere else but not in method call?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations, swagger-ui

Is it possible to set the @RequestHeader annotation anywhere else just not in the method parameter list? Below you can see my code:

```
@ApiOperation("Gather all details of a specific device, identified by its ID")
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK", response = DeviceResource.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Device not found", response = VndErrors.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Printer shell execution error", response = VndErrors.class)
})
@GetMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<DeviceResource> getDeviceById(
        @ApiParam(value = "ID of the device", required = true)
        @PathVariable String id,
        @RequestHeader(name = "X-NANO-APIKEY") String auth
) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new DeviceResource(deviceAccessor.getDeviceById(id)));
}
```

The problem is I use the method for other calls too, so I have to set the header in this situiation. But I don't want to set it. I only have to set it in the swagger-ui. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the request header from HttpServletRequest Object as well.

```
public ResponseEntity<DeviceResource> getDeviceById(
@ApiParam(value = "ID of the device", required = true)
@PathVariable String id,
HttpServletRequest request
) {
String auth = request.getHeader("X-NANO-APIKEY");
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have the problem that i am not able to set it in the swagger ui :/

Comment: You could use the `globalOperationParameters` in the docket definition